# Arrangement of $100$ articles numbered $n_{1},n_{2},n_{3},n_{4} \cdots n_{100}$.

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

> There are $100$ articles numbered $n_{1},n_{2},n_{3},n_{4} \cdots n_{100}$
>   They are arranged in all possible ways. How many arrangments would be there 
>   in which $n_{28}$ will always be before $n_{29}$

$a.)\ 5050\times 99! \\
b.)\ 5050\times 98! \\
\color{green}{c.)\ 4950\times 98!} \\
d.)\ 4950\times 99! \\ $

I integrated $n_{28}$ and $n_{29}$ in one term and concluded 
that answer will be $99!$.

But that's not in options.

I look for a short and simple way.

I have studied maths upto $12$th grade.

Comment: "Always" is weird. Always how? For any particular arrangement, either $n_{28}$ is before or after $n_{29}$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: you mean the word *always* is redundant in the question.

Comment: It is redundant in a way that makes it sound like you might mean something else, yes. You are seeking the number of *all* permutations with the condition that article 28 comes before 29. But the always seems to apply to the condition on a single permutation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Always be before" does not mean always be **immediately** before.
Half of the $100\times99 = 4950$ ways the two specified numbers can be placed satisfy the stipulations, and the rest can be permuted in $98!$ ways

Answer (score 4):

**Intuitive and Simple**

Use the symmetry of the problem. Half of the cases of all arrangements, which is half of $100!$ should be the answer. This can be written as $\frac{1}{2}\times 99\times100\times 98!$ which is $4950 \times 98!$

Answer (score 1):

As you can see the problem has asked to place n28 before n29 . It's not necessary that it comes just before . So by symmetry half of the times we permutate the things n29 will come before n29 .

Answer (score 0):

One more approach: once you have $k$ slot fixed for $n_{28}$, you have $n-k$ slots in which you can put $n_{29}$. Since you don't care about the remaining items, you have $98!$ ways to arrange them. Since this is true for 99 slots out of 100, you can use the well-known summation formula: 
$$
98! \cdot 99 + 98! \cdot 98 + \ldots 98! \cdot 1 = 98!(1+2+ \ldots 99) = 98! \cdot \frac{99 \cdot 100}{2} = 98! \cdot 4950
$$

Answer (score -1):

Of the total arrangements, half of them have n28 before n29 and other half arrangements have n28 after n29.
So,
  total arrangements =100!
  half of them = 100!/2=50*99!=50*99*98!=4950*98!
hope you understood!